# my form is making get request on same url, I don't know why it is doing it

Tags: javascript, html

I have login form, it is as follows, this will be let me login. I don't have experience with HTML and javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1> <b> Please sign in</b></h1>
        <div id="login">
            <form name="salesForm" id="submit_form">
             <div class="form-group" id="UserNameD" >
                <label for="UserName">Username</label>
                <input id="UserName" type="text" name="UserName" class="form-control" required style="color:black">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group" id="passwordD" >
                <label for="password">password</label>
                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required style="color:black">
              </div>
              <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="static/js/login.js?233"> </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have following javascript file as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit_form').submit(function(ev) {
    var form_data = $('#submit_form').serializeArray()
    console.log(form_data);
    $.ajax({
                    "type": "POST",
                    "async": false,
                    "url":'xxxx',
                    "data": form_data,
                    "cache": false,
                    "processData": false,
                     "contentType": false,
                    success: function ( res ) {
                        successcallback(res);

                    },
                    error: function( err ) {
                         alert("Login Fail");

                    }
                });

    function successcallback( res ) {
           window.location.replace("xxxx");
    }

   });
});
```

It is not working, it is making get request at / not url that I put in login.js.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add:

```
$('#submit_form').submit(function(ev) {
ev.preventDefault(); // prevent default form behavior
```

to prevent page reload after sumbit clicked